# Can I make Axis2 publish web service documentation similar to the one from .Net?

Tags: apache-axis, documentation-generation

When publishing a web service using .Net you automatically gets a neat documentation on the endpoint, listing all operation with comments from the source code, and pretty soap/xml samples.

Is there anyway to get something similar from a web service published using Axis2? Or I'm actually using IBM Rational Software Architect for Websphere, but it uses Axis2 for web service publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 has a feature to list services and operations, but it is not as complete as .Net. This feature is also not available when deploying a JAX-WS (Java EE 5) service into WebSphere (which internally uses Axis2).